# Are OpenGL indices and locations the same thing for uniforms and vertex attributes?

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, opengl-3, opengl-4

In the OpenGL Reference Pages, [some](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man4/html/glUniform.xhtml) functions are marked as using uniform locations, while [other](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man4/html/glGetActiveUniform.xhtml) functions are marked as using uniform indices. Are these the same thing?

Similarly for vertex attributes, [some](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man4/html/glEnableVertexAttribArray.xhtml) functions are marked as using vertex attribute indices, while [other](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man4/html/glGetAttribLocation.xhtml) functions are marked as using vertex attribute locations. Are these the same?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your first case, the *location* for an Uniform is different from the *index* used for `glGetActiveUniform()`.

For `glGetActiveUniform()` case, index is just a value between 0 and the value you get from `glGetProgram( GL_ACTIVE_UNIFORMS,...)` minus one. This API allows you to query any resources of the program, and you can iterate over all active uniforms with that method. The uniform locations may not start at 0, and may not be consecutive at all.

In your second example, `glGetAttribLocation()` and `glEnableVertexAttribArray()` both refer to the same index. The GL has a set of generic attributes, which are generally referenced by their indices, starting from 0. However, to make things a little bit more interesting, there is also [`glGetActiveAttrib()`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man4/html/glGetActiveAttrib.xhtml) which is similiar to the `glGetActiveUniform()` one: here, the index refers just to the list of active attributes (in the range 0 to the value you get from `glGetProgram( GL_ACTIVE_ATTRIBUTES,...)` minus one, and *not* to the actual attribute index/location. Again, this API allows you to iterate over all attributes which are present (and active).