# uniform location and attribute location - is it the same number series?

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

Is it OK to make (per-draw-call) **uniform** and (per-vertex) **attribute** to share same channel `(location = X)` explicitly?

**Vertex Shader** :-

```
layout(location = 2) in vec3 perVertex_pos;      
layout(location = 2) uniform vec3 perInstance_color;
//^ same "location = 2" ... valid?
```

I am trying to keep `location` to a low figure as much as possible to fix an error `C5102: input semantic attribute "ATTR" has too big of a numeric index`.

**References :**
https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Layout_Qualifier_(GLSL)
https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Uniform_(GLSL)/Explicit_Uniform_Location
They explain each type (uniform & attribute) individually, but do not tell whether I can share the index.

**Edit:** A similar-but-perpendicular question : [Are OpenGL indices and locations the same thing for uniforms and vertex attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30035861/are-opengl-indices-and-locations-the-same-thing-for-uniforms-and-vertex-attribut)

Comment: [OpenGL 4.6 API Core Profile Specification - 7.3.1 Program Interfaces, page 108](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.core.pdf#page=124&zoom=100,0,173):
*"Each entry in the active resource list **for an interface** is assigned **a unique unsigned integer index** in the range zero to N − 1, where N is the number of entries in the active resource list.*" - Uniforms and attributes are different types of interfaces.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, they can share indices. Attribute locations and uniform locations are unrelated.

Comment: May you provide some reference to make me rest in peace, please?

Comment: @javaLover I don't have a reference at hand, but you might be able to verify it by not specifying `location`, and checking the automatically assigned locations with `glGetAttribLocation` and `glGetUniformLocation`.